# How can I patch the Content of an AIR Application?

Tags: flash, air, patch

I have tried searching via Google with anything from Difference, Patching, etc. It all leads to the Update() and Update Framework, which is fine. However, I am creating an interactive motion graphic novel within AIR, which I plan to update content as I go. From my understanding, the Update Framework will update the entire AIR package.

For example, the main Desktop app is 80 KB, while external SWF will be loaded. The external will be in the application directory and included in the .AIR package. Right now, the first chapter is 4.7 MB, but it will grow as I add more content.

I will accept that I may be missing something from all the tutorials on the Update Framework and will graciously accept any advise. One thing I am thinking of doing is creating an AIR package with updated content to be copied into same app directory. Is this a possibility?

Comment: So why not have it just load new content from additional SWF file(s)? Each chapter is an external SWF saved as **chapter02.dat** or **chapter03.dat** etc.

Comment: @VC.One That is what I am considering. Right now, the directory has the main executable and the first chapter as a SWF. What I am trying to figure out is how to distribute the change. From your response, I am thinking you mean changing a xml file to indicate new content and the main application reads that dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at Vudu To Go, I thought of something that would help improve updates on both the main application and content. @VC.One also helped inspire this idea.

For content, I can use this [webpage](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b8f6c0-7ffe.html) as guidence.

If I understand it right, I can remove the Chapter1.swf from the main package, which reduces the main application. It also allows for Update Framework to only focus on that and reduces bandwidth. I can then use the air.net to show available chapters and the user can download them, which will go into the application directory. If I got it right, this process will main application to access the swf files the same way I am doing it right now.